# readonly sqlite on a server

Tags: java, performance, sqlite

A few people have asked about using sqlite on a server; obviously it's not a good choice if you have to write to the database.

What I am wondering about, is how well does it work in a read-only scenario? On the surface it seems it would work quite well: it supports concurrent access, and as long as we manage database updates in a smart way (restarts required...), it seems this is good.

In particular we are seeing really good performance, so this could be a big win.

Has anyone had bad experiences doing this? Any gotchas to watch out for? Anyone tried to scale this scenario in Java using sqlite4java?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: How often does the db need to be updated?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a Java database that is well tested for this scenario, for example the H2 database?

Comment: We'd be updating about once per day. We are interested in sqlite because of the spatial extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. If you just need concurrent read access you should be fine.